# Swift NSUnarchiver Error

Tags: swift, nskeyedarchiver

I get the following error when i try to unarchive a custom object

**'cannot decode object of class (PhotoList) for key (root); the class may be defined in source code or a library that is not linked'**

I currently have a version on the app store (v1.0, have issued an update via version TestFlight (v2.0) and this is where the error happens. The error doesn't happen on the same version builds via Xcode. Nothing has changed (that I can see!) that would have caused this.

Here is the code I have for archiving the object

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(VehicleList.instance)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "archiveName")
```

And here is the code I have for unarchiving the object

```
if let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("archiveName") as? NSData {
    let photoList : PhotoList = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! PhotoList
}
```

Comment: On which line does it crash? Also you are casting to wrong type. You should replace `PhotoList` with `VehicleList`

Comment: The VehicleList/PhotoList was a type from the source code - my bad!
It is crashing on the line below: 


let photoList : PhotoList = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! PhotoList

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was related to multiple targets. It seems when I duplicated targets, I swapped over the original target with another, so it was in fact a different target that couldn't unarchive the data.

So be careful when you create targets and make sure you don't mix them up! Hope this saves someone the amount of time it took me to figure this out!